# Is it a breaking change if I move a Thrift data structure from one file to another?

Tags: thrift, idl

If I have a service-specific file with Thrift definitions named serviceA.thrift:

```
struct ServiceError {
  1: required i16 code,
  2: required string message
}

struct Service Response {
  1: optional ServiceError error;
  ...
}
```

and want to move the definition of ServiceError to a separate file named common.thrift so it can be used in different services:

```
struct ServiceError {
  1: required i16 code,
  2: required string message
}
```

would it be a breaking change to update serviceA.thrift to use the new shared data structure:

```
include "common.thrift"

struct Service Response {
  1: optional common.ServiceError error;
  ...
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the wire format only knows numeric IDs<sup>1)</sup> which you don't change that should work seamlessly.

---

<sup>1) only exception to that rule are service method names</sup>